# Why is Polymer just a series of HTML files with JavaScript?

Tags: polymer

I'm starting to experiment with Polymer 1.0, and I noticed that the some of files included via *Bower* are broken up into the following three:

- polymer-micro.html
- polymer-mini.html
- polymer.html

And each file is imported via [*HTML Imports*](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) within the next one down the list. Then, the rest of the file is just JavaScript.

Perhaps, it's my lack of knowledge regarding [*HTML Imports*](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/), but is this a clever way to utilize dependency management for JavaScript without having to add a third-party library like *Browserify* for example?

Comment: Here's an explanation for why Polymer is layered into three. (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/experimental.html).

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal - Awesome! Can't believe I missed this. Thanks!